PHP Madelineproto getDownloadLink() method returns error
I try get download link of photo from a channel using Madelineproto and receive following exception:
The given data cannot be sent because it is not serializable.

$link = $this->api->getDownloadLink($message ['media'] ['webpage'] ['photo'], __DIR__ .'/../../../dl.php');

dl.php contains:
<?php

use danog\MadelineProto\API;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

API::downloadServer('/var/www/storage/madeline.session');

Before this exception I received:
Could not generate default download script (Please specify a download script URL when using getDownloadLink via CLI!), please create a dl.php file with the following content: <?php require 'vendor/autoload.php'; \danog\MadelineProto\API::downloadServer('/var/www/storage/madeline.session'); ?> and pass its URL to the second parameter of getDownloadLink

But now the file exists.
Also, I tryed pass as first parameter $message ['media'] ['webpage'] and $message ['media'] and just $message.
Google does not know, and I can't find an examples.

If it's matter: post created by Telegram Instant View
